# With cmake, how would you disable in-source builds?

Tags: build, cmake

I want to disallow people from cluttering our source tree with generated CMake files... and, more importantly, disallow them from stepping on existing `Makefiles` that are not part of the same build process we're using CMake for. (best not to ask)

The way I have come up with to do this is to have a few lines at the top of my `CMakeLists.txt`, as follows:

```
if("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}" STREQUAL "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}")
   message(SEND_ERROR "In-source builds are not allowed.")
endif("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}" STREQUAL "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}")
```

However, doing it this way seems too verbose. Additionally, if I try an in-source build it still creates the the `CMakeFiles/` directory, and the `CMakeCache.txt` file in the source tree before the error is thrown.

Am I missing a better way to do this?

Comment: This is the best solution that I've found so far. You could make the message more informative, though: message(FATAL_ERROR "In-source builds are not permitted. Make a separate folder for building:\nmkdir build; cd build; cmake ..\nBefore that, remove the files already created:\nrm -rf CMakeCache.txt CMakeFiles")

Comment: I wouldn't call it verbose if you closed the condition with just an `endif()`.

Comment: That's nice if you can just use `endif()` today. I think when I wrote this question, that was not possible.

Comment: @mpontillo did you later find a viable solution to this?

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon, I've since moved on from the project I'm discussing in this question, but if I believe the most-upvoted answers below, it looks like CMake has made progress in this area! Please let us know what works best for you.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not prevent CMake from creating CMakeCache.txt and CMakeFiles/ and thus it is no better than signaling an error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I like your way.  The cmake mailing list does a good job at answering these types of questions.

As a side note: you could create a "cmake" executable file in the directory which fails.  Depending on whether or not "." is in their path (on linux).  You could even symlink /bin/false.

In windows, I am not sure if a file in your current directory is found first or not.

Comment: Good idea; I'll interpret that as putting something on the $PATH that will intercept the call to cmake - or simply a separate script that will wrap it. Or maybe a standard alias. Unless there is a 'native' way to do this in cmake I think that's the way to go. And yes, I believe on Windows '.' is implicitly on the $PATH; on UNIX it is not, but we could always put a cmake wrapper somewhere else in the $PATH.

Comment: What sort of nutter has . on their path?

Comment: The fake "cmake" idea won't work by default, as usually "." won't be in their path.

Comment: I think the CMakeLists.txt solution is a little better despite the verbosity because it doesn't rely on the user having a particular path. Moreover, I will be putting that in all my future cmake setups.

Answer (score 58):

CMake has two undocumented options:
`CMAKE_DISABLE_SOURCE_CHANGES` and `CMAKE_DISABLE_IN_SOURCE_BUILD`

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)

# add this options before PROJECT keyword
set(CMAKE_DISABLE_SOURCE_CHANGES ON)
set(CMAKE_DISABLE_IN_SOURCE_BUILD ON)

project (HELLO)

add_executable (hello hello.cxx)
```

-

```
andrew@manchester:~/src% cmake .
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:160 (FILE):
  file attempted to write a file: /home/andrew/src/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log
  into a source directory.
```

/home/selivanov/cmake-2.8.8/Source/cmMakefile.cxx

```
bool cmMakefile::CanIWriteThisFile(const char* fileName)
{
  if ( !this->IsOn("CMAKE_DISABLE_SOURCE_CHANGES") )
    {
    return true;
    }
  // If we are doing an in-source build, than the test will always fail
  if ( cmSystemTools::SameFile(this->GetHomeDirectory(),
                               this->GetHomeOutputDirectory()) )
    {
    if ( this->IsOn("CMAKE_DISABLE_IN_SOURCE_BUILD") )
      {
      return false;
      }
    return true;
    }

  // Check if this is subdirectory of the source tree but not a
  // subdirectory of a build tree
  if ( cmSystemTools::IsSubDirectory(fileName,
      this->GetHomeDirectory()) &&
    !cmSystemTools::IsSubDirectory(fileName,
      this->GetHomeOutputDirectory()) )
    {
    return false;
    }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not prevent CMake from creating CMakeCache.txt and CMakeFiles/ and thus it is no better than signaling an error (and is worse in that it gives a cryptic message).

Comment: Just make a directory with name "CMakeCache.txt" to avoid creating cache file.

Comment: If they are undocumented you should be wary to use these options. They may change without warning in future versions.

Comment: Unfortunately I get regression errors using obscure CXX compiler combinations. It's probably best to not use undocumented options for good reasons.

Answer (score 7):

Include a function like [this one](https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/ITK/blob/master/CMake/PreventInSourceBuilds.cmake). It is similar to what you do with these differences:

1. It is encapsulated in a function, which is called when you include the `PreventInSourceBuilds.cmake` module. Your main CMakeLists.txt must include it:

   ```
   set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/CMake)
   include(PreventInSourceBuilds)
   ```
2. It uses [get_filename_component()](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command%3aget_filename_component) with REALPATH parameter that resolves symlinks before comparing the paths.

In case the github link changes, here's the module source code (which should be placed in a `PreventInSouceBuilds.cmake`, in a directory called `CMake`, in the above example):

```
#
# This function will prevent in-source builds
function(AssureOutOfSourceBuilds)
  # make sure the user doesn't play dirty with symlinks
  get_filename_component(srcdir "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}" REALPATH)
  get_filename_component(bindir "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}" REALPATH)

  # disallow in-source builds
  if("${srcdir}" STREQUAL "${bindir}")
    message("######################################################")
    message("# ITK should not be configured & built in the ITK source directory")
    message("# You must run cmake in a build directory.")
    message("# For example:")
    message("# mkdir ITK-Sandbox ; cd ITK-sandbox")
    message("# git clone http://itk.org/ITK.git # or download & unpack the source tarball")
    message("# mkdir ITK-build")
    message("# this will create the following directory structure")
    message("#")
    message("# ITK-Sandbox")
    message("#  +--ITK")
    message("#  +--ITK-build")
    message("#")
    message("# Then you can proceed to configure and build")
    message("# by using the following commands")
    message("#")
    message("# cd ITK-build")
    message("# cmake ../ITK # or ccmake, or cmake-gui ")
    message("# make")
    message("#")
    message("# NOTE: Given that you already tried to make an in-source build")
    message("#       CMake have already created several files & directories")
    message("#       in your source tree. run 'git status' to find them and")
    message("#       remove them by doing:")
    message("#")
    message("#       cd ITK-Sandbox/ITK")
    message("#       git clean -n -d")
    message("#       git clean -f -d")
    message("#       git checkout --")
    message("#")
    message("######################################################")
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Quitting configuration")
  endif()
endfunction()

AssureOutOfSourceBuilds()
```

Comment: Thanks. I've edited this answer to include the source code. I like this approach.

Answer (score 6):

I have a `cmake()` shell function in my `.bashrc`/`.zshrc` similar to this one:

```
function cmake() {
  # Don't invoke cmake from the top-of-tree
  if [ -e "CMakeLists.txt" ]
  then
    echo "CMakeLists.txt file present, cowardly refusing to invoke cmake..."
  else
    /usr/bin/cmake $*
  fi
}
```

I prefer this low ceremony solution. It got rid of my colleagues' biggest complaint when we switched to CMake, but it doesn't prevent people who *really* want to do an in-source/top-of-tree build from doing so—they can just invoke `/usr/bin/cmake` directly (or not use the wrapper function at all).  And it's *stupid* simple.

Comment: The problem with that is that is not portable and is not explicit in the sources.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure your .bashrc file like [this one](http://techbase.kde.org/Getting_Started/Increased_Productivity_in_KDE4_with_Scripts#.bashrc)

Look at the functions *cmakekde* and *kdebuild*. Set BUILD and SRC env. variables and edit these functions according to your needs. This will build only in *buildDir* rather than *srcDir*

Answer (score 0):

Just make the directory read-only by the people/processes doing the builds. Have a separate process that checks out to the directory from source control (you are using source control, right?), then makes it read-only.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, because of the way our source control and system works, it would be impractical to do it this way. I was looking for a more general solution.

Answer (score 0):

For those on Linux:

add to top-level CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(CMAKE_DISABLE_IN_SOURCE_BUILD ON)
```

create a file 'dotme' in your top-level or add to your .bashrc (globally):

```
#!/bin/bash
cmk() { if [ ! -e $1/CMakeLists.txt ] || ! grep -q "set(CMAKE_DISABLE_IN_SOURCE_BUILD ON)" $1/CMakeLists.txt;then /usr/bin/cmake $*;else echo "CMAKE_DISABLE_IN_SOURCE_BUILD ON";fi }

alias cmake=cmk
```

now run:

```
. ./dotme
```

when you try to run cmake in the top-level source tree:

```
$ cmake .
CMAKE_DISABLE_IN_SOURCE_BUILD ON
```

No CMakeFiles/ or CMakeCache.txt gets generated.

When doing out-of-source build and you need to run cmake first time just call the actual executable:

```
$ cd build
$ /usr/bin/cmake ..
```

Answer (score 0):

This is still the best answer for my purposes:

```
project(myproject)

if(PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR STREQUAL PROJECT_BINARY_DIR)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "In-source builds are not allowed")
endif()
```

or allow the build, but show a warning message:

```
if(PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR STREQUAL PROJECT_BINARY_DIR)
  message(WARNING "In-source builds are not recommended")
endif()
```

However, there does not appear to be a simple way to avoid `CMakeFiles/` and `CMakeCache.txt` being created in the source directory.