# Prevent running cmake in the root directory

Tags: makefile, cmake

Sometimes I forget I'm in the build folder and I run the command in the root directory. Well, maybe some of you have experienced that this creates a mess in the entire file hierarchy, as you have to delete CMakeFiles/ folder, config files, and files related to CPack and CTest. Is there a way I can add something to the Makefile at the root directory that prevents me from running cmake accidentally? I tried to add a target 'cmake' but this didn't work.

aa

**UPDATE**

I found the same question posted in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208681/with-cmake-how-would-you-disable-in-source-builds). I ended up adopting to put a function in my .bashrc file as suggested in that page:

```
function cmake() {
  # Don't invoke cmake from the top-of-tree
  if [ -e "CMakeLists.txt" ]
  then
    echo "CMakeLists.txt file present, cowardly refusing to invoke cmake..."
  else
    /usr/bin/cmake $*
  fi
}
```

Comment: 'root directory' probably doesn't mean what you think it means.

Answer (score 6):

You can check in your `CMakeLists.txt` if the source and binary directories are the same. Put something like this as the very first thing in your `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
if (CMAKE_BINARY_DIR STREQUAL CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Source and build directories cannot be the same.")
endif()
```

Comment: Great @JesperE, that made it! Almost. The problem now is that this still creates CMakeCache.txt and the CMakeFiles/ directory.

Comment: Yes, this does not seem possible to avoid, unfortunately. I think these files are created even before control is passed to the CMakeLists.txt file.

Comment: BUT You can clean it up in this case :} `file (REMOVE CMakeCache.txt)` , to be precise.

Comment: `file (REMOVE CMakeCache.txt)` does not actually work, because it appears to execute before the file is created.  Strangely, CMake seems to create the file _after_ FATAL_ERROR.  It's odd that CMake would strongly encourage out-of-source builds (for good reason!), and then make it so hard to prevent accidental in-source builds.