# CMake error "attempted to write a file ... into a source directory."

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cmake, trinitycore

I got errors after update CMake to version 3.12.1

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:174 (file):
  file attempted to write a file:
  /home/wow/TrinityCore/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log into a source directory.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:19 (project)


CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Unix Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

make is installed

```
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
```

g++ is installed too. Ubuntu Version 14.04.5.

How to solve that error?

Comment: Did you remove build directory and run cmake again?

Comment: yes, but it's the same error

Comment: The first error - "  file attempted to write a file:" - looks suspicious. Show your code up to the `project()` call.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Where can i find this? I never used cmake before... it's the TrinityCore Projekt

Comment: Looks like the OP set `CMAKE_DISABLE_IN_SOURCE_BUILD` and/or `CMAKE_DISABLE_SOURCE_CHANGES` (see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10306476/1896169))

Comment: @GoE It's the CMakeLists.txt file in the root directory of the project

Comment: My crystal ball says that you set `CMAKE_DISABLE_IN_SOURCE_BUILD` and/or `CMAKE_DISABLE_SOURCE_CHANGES`, then tried to do an in-source build. In other words, from the root directory of the project, you just wrote `cmake .`. Create a `build` subdirectory and run cmake inside there. For a decent project structure (it's still a WIP), see https://github.com/vector-of-bool/vector-of-bool.github.io/blob/master/_drafts/project-layout.md

Comment: @Justin: You guess seems to be right, TrinityCore's [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/TrinityCore/TrinityCore/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) sets exactly those variables.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CMAKE\_MAKE\_PROGRAM not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141608/cmake-make-program-not-found)

Answer (score 2):

As already noted in the comments, the message

```
file attempted to write a file ... into a source directory
```

is a result of `CMAKE_DISABLE_SOURCE_CHANGES` variable set in the project's `CMakeLists.txt`. This setting activates the check, that CMake project won't create any file under the source directory. (More precise description of this variable setting see in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208681/with-cmake-how-would-you-disable-in-source-builds)).

Normally, setting `CMAKE_DISABLE_SOURCE_CHANGES` variable is accompanied with setting `CMAKE_DISABLE_IN_SOURCE_BUILD` variable, with literal meaning:

**The project should NOT be built in-source.**

Solution is to build the project **out-of-source**, in the *build directory* which differs from the *source one*.

E.g. that way:

```
cd <project-dir>
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
```