# How to exclude CMake generated project files from Git

Tags: git, cmake

I have a CMake project and I would like to exclude the generated project files from version control.

From my understanding there is no way to force CMake to use a certain build directory. The user can specify any directory they want and therefore I cant exclude it in my .gitignore. Usually the user would place it in a directory called `build` inside the source directory and I would put that in .gitignore. But I had the crazy idea to call it `meta_build`, which led me to this problem. Also, an inexperienced user might do an in-source build. It's just a matter of time until someone accidentally checks in the generated project files.

Any ideas or workarounds for this matter are much appreciated.

Comment: Every CMake build directory contains e.g. a file `CMakeCache.txt`. So you could just tell the git to not commit any directory which has such file. Unfortunately, I don't know how to do that in git. I don't get your problem around `build` and `meta_build` directories, but forbidding *in-source builds* could be easily done in the CMake project itself: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208681/with-cmake-how-would-you-disable-in-source-builds.

Comment: You can always do `if (NOT "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/build" STREQUAL "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}") message(FATAL_ERROR "You shall not pass!!!") endif()` optionally just with a non fatal warning. Other than that you can probably just encourage the user to use the desired directory for the build, by providing a script for the cmake configuration/build and/or a `CMakePresets.json`. One additional trick that could work assuming noone uses a build directory matching one of your source directories would be to simply generate a `.gitignore` file in the binary dir.

Comment: @fabian Thanks, the `if` block mostly solves my problem. However the `**/CMakeFiles` and `**/CMakeCache.txt` are still created by the CMake run, so I added them to .gitignore. I also tried excluding all subdirectories containing these files, like @Tsyvarev suggested, but it seems it is not possible in git. @fabian, if you post an anwser I can accept it as solved.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is an issue for you because those other users are collaborating on the project and also potentially pushing to a shared remote. In that case, you have options:

- Set a convention for only building to a subdirectory with a common name. For example, [The PitchFork Layout's `build/`](https://api.csswg.org/bikeshed/?force=1&url=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vector-of-bool/pitchfork/develop/data/spec.bs#tld.build). I personally put all my builds in a `out/build/<build_name>` directory. Then you can just gitignore that one directory.
- Allow your collaborating users to put build anywhere they want in their local clone, and in order to avoid arbitrary explosion of the gitignore, tell them to use their `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/ignore`, or the local clone's `$GIT_DIR/info/exclude` ([docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_description)).
- You can hint users to use a particular build directory name(s) using presets: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html (see the `binaryDir` property for configuration presets).
- Technically you can write the gitignore on a filename basis independent of where the build directory is (Ex. listing out individually `*.exe`, etc.), but that sounds like a real pain in the butt- especially given that different buildsystem generators will have different build artifacts and specific buildsystem configuration files, and that different platforms have different prefixes and suffixes for target output file names (see for example [`CMAKE_EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX.html)).